# Increase width for date and event columns on the reputation tab

Tags: feature-request, design, localization, russian-stackoverflow

I know that most Stack Exchange sites here are in English. Accordingly, sizes of a lot of UI components are based on English words. But since localized versions of Stack Overflow sites exist - they need some unique settings. If unique settings are not possible, then global ones should be modified to satisfy design needs of localized sites. This has been a general idea.

In this particular case, I would ask to increase sizes for date and event columns in the reputation tab. As far as I see, current widths were chosen so that any possible English phrase fits into a single line:

> [image: eng]

But for current Russian translation some strings do not fit into a single line:

> [image: rus]

Of course, I could modify translation, but this will look like synthetic limitation.

Is it possible to increase width for previously mentioned columns on *Stack Overflow на русском* to allow them fit into single lines?

Comment: Out of curiosity, given this only has to do with localized Russian sites, why are you not posting on one of their metas?

Comment: @Oded I think such issue could be relevant for **any** localized site. So that why I posted it here.

Comment: The verbosity of certain languages varies a lot - Japanese has the opposite problem - even the longest English strings can end up being only a few characters...

Comment: @Oded Agreed. So allow to localized sites decide is a better solution.

Comment: Which is my point. You are asking for a solution that will only be correct for Russian sites - not Japanese sites.

Comment: @Oded if necessary settings will be get from some kind of transifex, why is this not a solution for everyone?

Comment: Not sure that's the solution we would go for. This is a pure display issue, not a translation issue.

Comment: @Oded so, make flexible layouts o_O