# Show votes cast table content in one line if possible

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, profile-page, votes-tab

There is the table on the [votes tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=votes):

> [image: Votes]

As you see the dates displayed in two lines despite enough horizontal place to show them in one line.

It looks ever more weird for non-English sites, like on ruSO:

> [image: Голоса]

Here recent votes date strings are wider then old ones, but still displayed in one-line (I didn't check but there is non-breaking space probably used in translations). Even more the second column with vote type is also affected.

So my suggestion is allow to display such a values in one line in votes cast table (without using some hacks like non-breaking space in translations).

Related 3yo issue: [Increase width for date and event columns on the reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290540/339911)

Comment: So, they'll have to increase the width of the first 2 rows where necessary. That would fix it, right?

Comment: @Mast Not rows, but columns. For all columns except last one :) But we need to check other non-English sites to prevent premature fixes.

Comment: *facepalm* Naturally, columns. And yes, for the exact width (and that could get tricky with responsiveness), all non-English sites should be checked too. The obvious side-effect of this is going to be that there will be less room remaining for the third column and I don't know what kind of side-effects that's going to have. Might be trading one problem for another.

Comment: @Mast the one obvious side-effect is more multiline rows for the posts with long enough title. But in general votes cast table will be more compact then before, since regular title is short as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current design of the page explicitly makes dates in this column span over two lines. It is something that will eventually be redesigned and we will take this feedback into account (but it is pretty low priority right now, and no idea when/if that might happen, so marking as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for the time being).

Comment: The column of vote type should also be taken a bit of care. In [es.so] it spans over three lines in certain cases -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE5IO.png

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' it seems that using of non-breaking space will fix the word-wrapping issue, so I'm going to update translations accordingly

Comment: @αλεχολυτ sounds great. I don't know how to use a non-breaking space in traducir.win, though.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' just type `Alt+0160` on the numpad part of keyboard. You'll see it as a regular space in edit field after that, but that will be a non-breaking space.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ great, I see that with Macbook it is `⌥+Space`.